# Finding maximum or minimum largest absolute value for any number of cells above it

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I want to find the largest value(positive or negative) from a certain number of cells above it and paste under it.
Below is the code for finding the largest value for 6 cells above the output cell. But I do not know how to find the largest value if the number of cells above it to be analyzed is more or less than 6. It is looped to find values of multiple groups of cells with having exactly "n" number of cells above it and create an empty cell to find the max. I have created the loop but I am stuck at this one. I think my approach is incorrect. I can know how many cases are there. I can create a input box to ask the user to give how many cases so that we can create an empty row after that many rows. But I am stuck at the formula to use to calculate the value. I cannot insert a variable inside the formula.
If there is any other approach to to do this, then I am up for it.

```
Sub maxvalue()
Dim iRow As Integer, iCol As Integer
Dim oRng As Range
Dim nRng As Range
Set oRng = Range("A4")
iRow = oRng.Row
iCol = oRng.Column
Do
   If Cells(iRow + 1, iCol) <> Cells(iRow, iCol) Then
        Cells(iRow + 1, iCol).EntireRow.Insert Shift:=xlDown
        Cells(iRow + 1, iCol + 1).Value = "max"
        Cells(iRow + 1, iCol + 2) _
            .FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(ABS(MAX(R[-6]C:R[-1]C))<ABS(MIN(R[-6]C:R[-1]C)),MIN(R[-6]C:R[-1]C),MAX(R[-6]C:R[-1]C))"
        iRow = iRow + 2
Else
    iRow = iRow + 1
End If
Loop While Not Cells(iRow, iCol).Text = ""
End Sub
```

Below is the picture of what I am working with and what I am expecting:
[image]

Comment: Could you upload some sample data and point out which value you want to pull ? If you are finding MAXIMUM Absolute then previous or forward position doesn't matters !!

Comment: @RajeshS I have updated the post for clarity.

Comment: so you need VBA solution or formula? One more thing I want to ask your Sample data shows every 7th value is Max ! Are you finding Max after nth Row ?

Comment: @RajeshS I do not know how can I fix from the code that I have. If there is a problem with it, then I might need VBA solution. But if only formula can be modified so that I can get a max after nth row, then it is perfect for me. I want nth row because some times there 10 cases or may be only 3 cases.

Comment: I've created two different formula, 1st is returning every 7th Value in Column and 2nd is returning value after every 7th value in Column. Now confirm will this work for you?

Comment: I do not think this will work because sometimes I need to find max values of every 10 cases.

Comment: I have done it. `Set xRange = Range(Cells(iRow, iCol + 4), Cells(iRow - mergervalue, iCol + 4))`
            `xMax = Val(WorksheetFunction.Max(xRange))`
            `xMin = Val(WorksheetFunction.Min(xRange))`
            `If Abs(xMax) > Abs(xMin) Then`
                `Cells(iRow + 1, iCol + 4) = xMax`
                    `Else:  Cells(iRow + 1, iCol + 4) = xMin`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/78571/discussion-between-rajesh-s-and-baaki-nira).

Answer (score 2):

```
=MAX($A$1:INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW()-1,COLUMN())))
```

Selects maximal value in the cells above in the same column (do not use in the cell in the first row). Needs "A1" address notation.

```
=MAX(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(1,COLUMN()), False):R[-1]C)
```

Selects maximal value in the cells above in the same column (do not use in the cell in the first row too). Needs "R1C1" address notation.

PS. I have national Excel only, so the minor errors maybe in the formulas. But I think it's enough to understand the idea of them.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. But I cannot give the reference to the cell like $A$1 because I want to find max values after every certain number of row but not from the top. And I think there is a problem with second one. I cannot use it.

Comment: *I want to find max values after every certain number of row but not from the top* What's a problem? construct both starting and finishing address as shown above.

Comment: It is because there are more than 500 max values that I need to find from every nth row above it and it is hectic to input starting and finishing address in each cells.

Comment: You do not need INPUT it. See code - the address of the last cell is relative to current cell, the address of the first cell is absolute. As I understand You need both addresses to be relative - do it.

Comment: I understand the last cell is relative, but i want first cell also to be relative. I want first cell to be only 6 rows or 7 rows or 10 rows above the last cell every time. Your code will return the value from the top of the cell to the last cell above the output box.